# FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken() not returning any token

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using FCM for push notifications in my android project. Here is my setup,

Manifest:

```
        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService.java:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
        @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
       //pushToServer
    } 
...
}
```

in my activity class I use the following code to push the FCM token to server:

```
 FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
               //pushToServer
            }
        });
```

This works fine on all of my test devices. But one of my users reported that he is not able to receive any notification. So, I checked the database and found out that his phone is not pushing any token to the server. He is using pixel 4a and is able to receive notifications from other apps. Unfortunately, I don’t have access to that device. Does anyone know what’s the issue here?

**UPDATE: ** `task.getException().getMessage()` returns the following error, `TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS`.

Comment: at your activtity class, did you handle if task is not successful?

Comment: No, what are the chances of the task being unsuccessful?

Comment: In `task.isSuccessful()`, you are pushing `token` to server but in the else block, you should push `task.getException().getMessage()` to server then you will know the reason whenever someone's device doesn't push the token.

Comment: task.getException().getMessage() returns the following error, TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS.